# how do I calculate download speed in UWP BackgroundDownloader?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

how do I calculate the BackgroundDownload latency/speed, e.g: 367kb/s or 5mb/s?

so far, the only potentially useful fields I know exposed by the `BackgroundDownloadProgress` class are `BytesReceived` and `TotalBytesToReceive`. at first I thought I can make use of the `BytesReceived` field but then I figured out that it's cumulative bytes since the beginning of the download operation, not the newly received chunk/bytes..

[image: available fields in BackgroundDownloadProgress]

I know there must be a way to achieve this because I saw the Store team has implemented this in the store app:

[image]

Comment: `BytesReceived` at (nth) second - `BytesReceived` at (n-1)th second should give you the value of the bytes received in between n-1 and nth second. Which is basically what you need..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a timer that ticks at an interval of 1 second, and count the bytes downloaded between two ticks.

The following code is unpolished, it does not format the speed to MB/s, and the timer keeps ticking after the download is done, and exception case like cancel/restart is not handled, I just give you an idea how to use a timer and a counter to do the calculation.

```
DispatcherTimer timer;
ulong bytesReceivedAtLastTick;

private async void StartDownload()
{
    BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
    DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile);
    timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
    timer.Tick += (s, e) => {
        var bytesReceivedAtThisTick = download.Progress.BytesReceived;
        var bytesPerSecond = bytesReceivedAtThisTick - bytesReceivedAtLastTick;
        Log($"Download speed: {bytesPerSecond} B/s");
        bytesReceivedAtLastTick = bytesReceivedAtThisTick;
    };
    timer.Start();

    await download.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);
}
```